# How to read a string in .pc file

Tags: proc

I am writing a program to connect the database in c++ in a file with .pcg extension. I am trying to input name (with spaces between first name and last name). I have defined the variable as char name[40]. But name variable stores only the first name and the rejects the part after the space. How to get the whole name in the name variable? I have tried "string name". I'm using g++ compiler and it's giving error.

Comment: It's very difficult to guess what might be wrong when you post absolutely zero code so we know what you're doing. Please edit your question and post the code; saying "I have tried "string name" is meaningless, and so is "it's giving error" with no information about what "error" means. We can't see your screen or read your mind from here, so we only know what you include in your question. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has suggestions on how to write questions so you improve your chances of getting an answer.